# dirinfor.EnumerateFiles -> Error

Tags: c#, linq

the following statement has an error, help to fix it.

```
 long siz = dirinfo.EnumerateFiles().Sum(file => file.length);
```

> 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' does not contain a definition for
>   'EnumerateFiles' and no extension method 'EnumerateFiles' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there is any name space required? I already put the namespace `System.IO`.

As all of you said i changed the code and

static long dirsize(DirectoryInfo dirinfo,bool includesubdir)
    {
 siz += dirinfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(dire => dirsize(dire, true));

}

when i am using it it gives an error as 
cannot convert from fileinfo to directoryinfo .

my question is will i get the one particular directory size by changing the directoryinfo to fileinfo ...? is it possible...? Please help me out to fix it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4? This is new in .NET 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232

Comment: @Gomathipriya then there is no EnumerateFiles method

Comment: @leppie that should be an answer :)

Comment: will it work only on the .NET 4...? If yes then how to use DirectoryInfo in .Net 3.5...?

Comment: @Gomathipriya: You can use `DirecoryInfo.GetFiles()`

Comment: @leppie & lazyberezovsky:  in which situation DirectoryInfo are used. it is available in .NET 3.5 , how to use it.

Comment: is it Possible to find the size of Directory by using this DirectoryInfo...?

Answer (score 2):

In .Net Framework prior to 4.0 you can use

```
long siz = dirinfo.GetFiles().Sum(file => file.Length);
```

Actually in your case there is no difference. Because you should anyway enumerate all files to calculate size (EnumerateFiles returns files one-by-one, GetFiles returns all files).

Comment: But _later_ than .NET 2.0 (for LINQ's `Sum`).

Comment: @GrantThomas so, we found his Framework - either 3.0 or 3.5 :)

Comment: will it show all the sub directories length...? if no means how to get it...?

Comment: @Gomathipriya: Use the `GetFiles(string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)` overload.

Comment: @Gomathipriya use `GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using a framework version lower than .NET 4.

[`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) was added with .NET 4.
Then you could use [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead which loads all into memory first and was available since 1.1.

Another (untested) approach here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12782/File-System-Enumerator-using-lazy-matching

Answer (score 1):

[`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method came with .NET 4.0.

You should download [`.NET Framework 4.0`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) version.

Try to use [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method instead of and it exists since .NET Framework 1.1.

> Returns a file list from the current directory.

Comment: *should* download the .NET 4? That's certainly desirable for many, but not necessarily practical for most.

Comment: @GrantThomas But `EnumerateFiles()` came with .NET 4.0. How he can use it without updated version of .net framework?

Comment: I would definitely consider an alternative, at least as a suggestion, before being so cavalier as recommending and entire framework installation. Don't get me wrong, it's good advice but bad form. I would hate for an OP to blindly follow advice and their next comment be 'soo, I installed .NET 4 on our live server and all our sites went down...', for instance. For a developer just developing 'stuff', yeah, get the new stuff, for people with real problems, suggesting they change something so drastically is often more dangerous than it is fruitful.